# How to disable Emacs asking if user wants to save abbrevs defined with :system property in a major mode

Tags: major-mode, abbrev

My Emacs version is 27.1

I am developing a major mode and I want to include some abbrevs to ship with it. I noticed that Emacs asks if user wants to save the abbrevs even if abbrevs have property :system t.

Here is the sample code:

```
(defun abbrev-test-generate-abbrevs ()

  (define-abbrev
    abbrev-test-mode-abbrev-table
    "test1"
    "test1\ntest1\ndone"
    nil
    :system t))


(define-derived-mode abbrev-test-mode prog-mode "TEST ABBR"
  ""
  
  (clear-abbrev-table abbrev-test-mode-abbrev-table)
  (abbrev-test-generate-abbrevs))

(provide 'abbrev-test-mode)
```

Listing abbrevs after `M-x abbrev-test-mode` correctly notes that "test1" is a system abbrev:

```
(abbrev-test-mode-abbrev-table)

"test1" (sys)       0 "test1
test1
done"
```

Yet Emacs asks if I want to save abbrevs when I exit.

The Elisp reference in Emacs, as well as [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Abbrev-Properties.html) specify that abbrevs with :system property non-nil are not saved. Is that a bug or is the documentation wrong? Or do I misunderstand?

I do not want to pester the users with save prompts for abbrevs that are part of the mode, unless they define their own abbrevs. Is that possible? If not, is there a more bare-bones snippeting functionality that I can use to write my own snippeting functions?

Using yasnippet is overkill for what I want to do. I just need the simplest possible snippet expansion and abbrev functionality is perfect for me, except this saving prompts.

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Comment: `clear-abbrev-table` sets `abbrevs-changed` to `t`, which then causes the prompt to save.

Comment: This isn't quite the exact thing you're asking about, as it doesn't have anything to do with this `:system` property, but for the general idea of not asking to save abbreviations, see [the emacs wiki](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/AbbrevMode#h5o-2): you can set `(setq save-abbrevs 'silently)`.